# SSRS server gives a 401 Unauthorised response, but only when called via the APIs

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am trying to run an SSRS report from a server in my application, downloading the result as a PDF. To do this, I am supplying Network Credentials for a user on the server with permission to run the report.

This all works fine with my local Developer copy of SSRS, I can run the report and happily go on to save it. However when I have SSRS running on a server and point the application at that, I instantly get a 401 Unauthorised error upon trying to run the report.

I can access the same remote server via my browser on the same computer I am trying to run the application on, using the same credentials that are failing in the application, and successfully run the report in question. None of the solutions that are already available online seem to apply/help.

Below is the code I am using to try to execute the report - ReportingUsername, ReportingPassword are being set to the credentials that work in the browser, ReportingDomain is being set to the name of the PC as it uses a local account (this was a troubleshooting step, I previously didn't have it which also didn't work), setting PreAuthenticate was another troubleshooting step. ReportServerUrl is http://server/ReportServer (the server is running as the default instance on port 80), and JCReportFolder is set to the folder that the report lives in on the server.

ReportKey is just the parameter that is used to run the report.

```
//setup credentials and URL of report execution service
ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService();
NetworkCredential nwk = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ReportingUsername, ReportingPassword, ReportingDomain);
rs.Credentials = nwk;
rs.PreAuthenticate = true;
rs.Url = ReportServerUrl + "/" + "reportexecution2005.asmx";
rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = new ExecutionHeader();
var executionInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
executionInfo = rs.LoadReport("/" + JCReportFolder + "/" + reportName, null);

//set report key
List<ParameterValue> parameters = new List<ParameterValue>();
parameters.Add(new ParameterValue { Name = "ReportKey", Value = reportKey });
rs.SetExecutionParameters(parameters.ToArray(), "en-US");


string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>";
string mimeType;
string encoding;
string[] streamId;
Warning[] warning;

var result = rs.Render("PDF", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out encoding, out warning, out streamId);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Tried so far:

- Confirmed server is not using Kerberos authentication, set to NTLM
- Checked account in use has full permissions to report and can access the report in web browser (from the same machine as is getting the 401 when run through the C# code), even tried making it an admin temporarily to see if that would help
- DB Connection uses stored credentials on the report server, not the supplied credentials, so it is not the issue
- Machine has full access through the firewall and can see the SSRS machine

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to remote database to debug issue.  I believe you should be using Default Credentials (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials?force_isolation=true&view=net-5.0)  which in a connection string Is Integrated Security=true; and on login window of SSMS it is windows credentials.  You need access to database from remove machine to perform report.

Comment: Thanks for the response @jdweng, however I specifically want to be using different windows credentials to the one the user is currently running as - it appears to me as though default credentials will just make it authenticate as the current user which will definitely not have access

Comment: You have to be careful of not allowing hackers to get access to a server.  Many networks do not allow the use of username, password for credentials to prevent hackers being able to break into a network.  They only allow secure connection from inside a network and give very little access from outside a firewall.  See Roles : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs

Comment: What are the versions of your local and target SQL Server? Does request to `http://server/ReportServer/reportexecution2005.asmx?wsdl` succeed?

Comment: Hi @JosefBláha both are 2019 (local is Developer and the server is running Standard SQL). I can happily load the WSDL at that address without any issue (authenticating with the same credentials my application is using to run the report)

Comment: Which call fails? The first one `LoadReport`?

Comment: Yes that's right, this line: executionInfo = rs.LoadReport("/" + JCReportFolder + "/" + reportName, null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after much head scratching this turned out to be an utterly absurd issue.

It turns out that setting ReportExecutionService.Url for some reason clears ReportExecutionService.Credentials. Simply moving the line

```
rs.Credentials = nwk;
```

to just before

```
executionInfo = rs.LoadReport("/" + JCReportFolder + "/" + reportName, null);
```

completely resolved the issue.

My guess is that I didn't experience the problem locally because the application was actually defaulting to execution as my local account which is an administrator, and therefore masking the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that .net is using a supported version of TLS, we ran into seemingly random auth issues when MS increased the default TLS version used by windows server.

`System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

Comment: Thanks @Joral unfortunately I have not got to the stage of setting up a certificate and running TLS, I am just making the call over port 80 for now.